# how to rename a file and keep the original

Tags: python, rename

I would like to keep unaltered the template.txt file after I insert some text into it and save the altered text file with a new name. Currently, my code overwrites the template.txt.

```
f = open("template.txt", "r")
contents = f.readlines()
f.close()
#insert the new text at line = 2
contents.insert(2, "This is a custom inserted line \n")
#open the file again and write the contents
f = open("template.txt", "w")
contents = "".join(contents)
f.write(contents)
f.close()
os.rename('template.txt', 'new_file.txt')
```

Comment: Write to a new file (ie: `new_file.txt`) directly instead?

Comment: change `f = open("template.txt", "w")` to sth like `f = open("template_new.txt", "w")` and remove os.rename since your new content will be saved in `template_new.txt` so you dont need to rename any file.

Comment: thanks @FilipMłynarski

Comment: The trivial name for renaming a file while keeping the original is "copying".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As people have mentioned, you're going to want to copy the contents of `template.txt` into a new file and then edit this new file. This allows you to keep the original file unmodified and you don't have to worry about renaming files at the end. Another tip: the `with open(file) as f` syntax keeps you from having to remember to close files when you're editing them and is the recommended way of working with files in python

```
with open("template.txt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    with open("new_file.txt", "w+") as n:
        lines.insert(2, "This is a custom inserted line \n")
        n.writelines(lines)
```

Comment: The string that I insert is in the format: string_1="hello Bob", string_2="hello Mary", etc. How can create a for loop and concatenate the iterator to pick up every time a different string? E.g., `for i in range(1,5,1): blah blah lines.insert(2,string_$i\n)`